# Run t-sql script into ssrs 2012 with date parameter and select from (select) query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, select, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I want to report a script which contains a Select from(Select) , when I just run the second Select I have no problem but When I put the hole script it loads and nothing happen.

Here's my code :

```
SELECT top 100 *,
       CASE
           WHEN Frequency='1'
                AND DATEDIFF(HOUR, T.MeasurementDate, T.nextMeasurement) > 1 THEN 'Missing Hour(s)'
           WHEN Frequency='1'
                AND T.MeasurementDate = T.maxMeasurement
                AND DATEDIFF(HOUR, T.maxMeasurement, CONVERT(DATE, @EndDate)) > 1 THEN 'Missing Max Hour(s)'
           WHEN Frequency='2'
                AND DATEDIFF(DAY, T.MeasurementDate, T.nextMeasurement) > 1 THEN 'Missing Day(s)'
           WHEN Frequency='2'
                AND T.MeasurementDate = T.maxMeasurement
                AND DATEDIFF(DAY, T.maxMeasurement, CONVERT(DATE, @EndDate)) > 1 THEN 'Missing Max Day(s)'
           ELSE 'OK'
       END AS [Verification] INTO #tt FROM
    (SELECT top 100 Flow.Id AS idFlow, Flow.ComponentId, Flow.Frequency, pip.Name AS PipelineName, LEAD(Flow.MeasurementDate) OVER (Partition BY ComponentId, NominationCycle, LocationType, Frequency, FlowTypeId, UnitofMeasurement
                                                                                                                                    ORDER BY MeasurementDate) nextMeasurement, MAX(Flow.MeasurementDate) OVER (PARTITION BY ComponentId, NominationCycle, LocationType, Frequency, FlowTypeId, UnitofMeasurement) maxMeasurement
     FROM BentekDatabase.dbo.Flow Flow
     INNER JOIN BentekDatabase.dbo.Pipeline pip ON Flow.PipelineId = pip.id
     WHERE ScheduledVolume IS NOT NULL
         AND MeasurementDate BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate) AS T
SELECT COUNT (*)
FROM #tt
WHERE Verification != 'OK'
```

PS : The code run perfectly in SSMs when I declare values for 2 parameter.
I want to display the result of the last query ( select count (*) from #tt where Verification != 'OK') in a new page report results, which will contain the result of all my other queries too.
ANy Idea ?

Comment: I would guess the account associated with SSRS does not have full permissions. Try use CTE or variable table.

Comment: I am the administrator, I don't know why I have to use CTE if my script runs perfectly in SSMS

Comment: Can you check if the parameters are passed properly while called from SSRS? you can check the actual query executed by running a trace. For any case it should at least return 0 for the count